# PHP PDO parameterized table name not working in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a class that contains methods that query the database for information and then return a variable which value is the prepared version of the sql query,  after "`execute()`" and "`setFetchMode()`", the function returns that same variable.

In another file I create an object of that class, and call that method which I assign as the value of another variable so that I can `fetch()` it on a while loop. The problem is that all of that happens without any apparent errors but the data that I request from the database is not retrieved.

```
<?php
class DatabaseContent{

    private $sql = "SELECT * FROM :table ";

    public function fetchAllRows($table, $rowOrder, $direction, $conn){
        $this->sql .= "ORDER BY :roworder :direction ";
        $q = $conn->prepare($this->sql);
        $q->execute(array(':table'=>$table, ':roworder'=>$rowOrder, ':direction'=>$direction));
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $q;
    }
```

And this is the file where I create the object

```
<?php
                   $table = "topics";
                   $rowOrder = "topic_id";
                   $direction = "ASC";

                   $q = new DatabaseContent; 
                   $n = $q->fetchAllRows($table, $rowOrder, $direction,$conn);

                            while($row = $n->fetch()):
                                echo '<a href="categoria/categoria.php"><li>'.$row['topic_name'].'</li></a>';
                            endwhile;
                ?>
```

Comment: I think `$q->setFetchMode` should be called before `$q->execute`

Comment: You're breaking the first and foremost rule in binding. **You cannot bind tables and/or columns.**

Comment: Add `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I really didn't know that you cannot bind tables and columns, so I couldn't search for something specific, that's why I didn't know that the answer for this already existed. I understand you had to flag it as a duplicate, but was it really necessary to vote it down??? Now I can't ask more questions cause I got more than two down votes. Sometimes you guys here on stackoverflow are really harsh with other people. But anyway thanks for the answer it was useful in some way.

Comment: When it comes to questions like these, they are closed with duplicates because Stack wants us to do that. Otherwise, the questions/answers would just keep piling up. If you feel the question should be reopened, you can flag your question and let the moderators know. I don't run Stack, I merely go by their rules. Don't always assume downvotes coming from a person in particular. I rectified that, but remember: There is/was more than one person who visited your question.